# Flurry only track my Iphone 6

Tags: iphone, swift, tracking, flurry, usersession

I followed the installation for Flurry: https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/#swift1
and I am possible to track User Events and User Sessions.

my problem right now is, that I was possible to track a Button on my Iphone 6, but not on my Iphone 5! On my Iphone 5 it only track the User Session.

I coded my App with Xcode Swift. Any solutions?

Regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the event data has been stored on the disk of your iPhone5. You need to either close the app with the home button or relaunch the app to guarantee the event data reports back to Flurry.